# Opening and closing a div from a link with json data

Tags: jquery, html, json, hide, show

I have information picked up from a json file and display it as a link. I would like to be able to hide and show a div when the link is clicked.

Here is my code.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
         var link = '';
         $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {

          link += "<li><a href='" +('#newuser')+ "'>"+ value.name +"</a></li>";

       $('#user').append(output);
    });
```

```html
    $("a href").click(function(){
        $(".main").hide();
      $(".main2").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please list out what your attempts have been to achieve the hide/show?

Comment: just added my code

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

- Your `$('#user').append(output);` is obsolete as you are referring to
  an unknown output variable.
- Your `('#newuser')` will only create new links with same id it
  appears like, you might want to have a unique id if you need one.
- Instead of `a href` , if you could bind the clik event to a class/id it'll make your code cleaner.
- Click the first link to see it working from the snippet.

```js
var testFunc = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function(data) {
    var html = "";
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      html += "<li><a href= '#' class= 'linkClicked'>" + val.username + "</li>";
    });
    $('#user').append(html);
    $(".linkClicked").click(function() {
      $(".main").hide();
      $(".main2").show();
    });
  });
}

testFunc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="user">

  </ul>
  <div class="main">This is the content to be hidden</div>
  <div class="main2">This is the content to be shown</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't want to work for me, but it works in the example :-(

Comment: the console doesn't give me any errors which is so annoying

Comment: This example is to guide you. I do not have any idea what the `main` and `main2` would appear to be. Also I have no clue of how the `example.json` looks like but if you follow the example along the same lines, you should arrive at the expected output. It is a simple ajax 101 question.

Comment: what you have shown me is right so I have no idea why it won't work when I try it

Comment: Try debugging it at each step. 1. Is your json content even loading? 2. Do you have all the html elements you are looking up for?

Comment: Could you let me know what you've tried so far? You may edit your own post to update hdd question